# Lua script to alter table caption in pandoc output

Tags: lua, latex, pandoc

I'm trying to write a lua filter to grab the heading from a table, run some operations on it, and return a new heading. I've done similar things with links, but I'm having no luck with tables.

Here's a simplified version of what I've done:

Input file:

```
# input

Some text here.

[link](www.google.com)

Table: table caption

|number|letter|
|:-----|-----:|
|1|b|
|2|d|
```

Lua filter that works (replaces `www.google.com` with `abc`):

```
return {{
    Link = function (el)
    el.target = "abc"
    return el
    end
    }}
```

Filter that doesn't work (it just removes the table and returns nothing):

```
return {{
    Table = function (el)
    el.caption = "abc"
    return el
    end
    }}
```

Command: `pandoc --lua-filter link.lua --lua-filter caption.lua input.md -o output.tex`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? According to the docs, `link.target` is a string, but `table.caption` is some other animal. But I can't find any explanation of what it is, except that it contains two elements (`short` and `long`).

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried `el.caption = {short = "abc", long = "abc"}` which keeps the table, but the `abc` doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: @Luatic Curious. My uneducated guess is that you've got the right syntax, but that `short` and `long` aren't strings either. Thanks!

Unfortunately, replacing `short` and `long` with `pandoc.List[table]` (where `table` is a lua table, not a pandoc table) gets the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The caption must be a list of blocks

```lua
el.caption = {pandoc.Plain 'abc'}
```

or the value must be assigned to the `long` field of the caption:

```lua
el.caption.long = {'abc'}
```

If this still doesn't work, then it's likely because of an older pandoc version (pre 2.19): those were stricter about how captions must be structured.